# How to test IsMobileDevice

Tags: visual-studio-2013, asp.net-mvc-5

Build a site and using IsMobileDevice.
But how can I test without publish my site and browse to it with my mobile?

Have tried http://www.responsinator.com/ and others and it only looks at size.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Ripple Emulator](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ripple-emulator-beta/geelfhphabnejjhdalkjhgipohgpdnoc?hl=en) or you can use the User Agent Override feature of Chrome Developer Tools to change your user agent. You can also find many other Chrome or Firefox extensions which help you change your user agent. [IsMobileDevice](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.httpcapabilitiesbase.ismobiledevice%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) [works by checking the user agent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1829089/how-does-ismobiledevice-work), so this should help you get what you want.

[image]