# How reliable is HttpBrowserCapabilities.IsMobileDevice?

Tags: c#, asp.net, mobile

Can [IsMobileDevice](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.httpcapabilitiesbase.ismobiledevice%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) be relied upon for helping create mobile-friendly websites? I have tested it on a range different devices but I am not sure how accurate/reliable it is, because I've always read and been told that you cannot detect (from a server-side language) a mobile device.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1829089/how-does-ismobiledevice-work