# Request.Browser.IsMobileDevice works on one server but not another?

Tags: asp.net

I am using the command Request.Browser.IsMobileDevice to load a mobile site js and html, it works great locally and on our dev server, but not on our staging server.

The .net and IIS version is the exact same, is there anything else that controls this command

Thanks

Comment: "great locally... not staging server" does this mean that it works completely correctly locally, and not at all on the staging server? Can you describe what you are experiencing in more detail

Answer (score 0):

this seems to be dependent on the .browser files:
[How does IsMobileDevice work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1829089/how-does-ismobiledevice-work)

could the .browser files be different on the different mahcines?