# Controller.HttpContext.Request.Browser.IsMobileDevice is false on Production server

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a MVC3 web application, I followed the instruction is below link to make my site mobile friendly,

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ABetterASPNETMVCMobileDeviceCapabilitiesViewEngine.aspx

everything is fine on my local IIS and it works when I connect to my local site via Mobile device,

I uploaded the site to the production server but it doesn't work, I traced the site and I figured out that on production server `someController.HttpContext.Request.Browser.IsMobileDevice` return false when I brows even with the mobile device. The mobile device is the same as in local tests.

Can everyone give me a clue?

### Edit 1

`someController.HttpContext.Request.UserAgent` is `User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.1.2; en-us; GT-N7000 Build/JZO54K) AppleWebKit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/534.30`

### Edit 2

I am using `.net4` and I can access to production server via `WebSitePanel` I don't have direct access to server.

Comment: You may want to read this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1829089/how-does-ismobiledevice-work

Comment: @RGraham The link doesn't help

Comment: I disagree. It explains why it works on your local machine (where you have your own `.browser` file) and why it doesn't on your server (presumably it has a different `.browser` file) and also why `IsMobileDevice` may not be a suitable method for attempting to detect mobile devices

Comment: @RGraham I mean the solution needs to make change on server but I don't have direct access to server to make some modifications

Comment: @RGraham Thanks for your hint, I found a way to fix the problem without manipulating server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution which doesn't need to change the server

```
   var isMobile= false;
    string u = Request.UserAgent;//ServerVariables["HTTP_USER_AGENT"];
    Regex b = new Regex(@"(android|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|mobile.+firefox|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows ce|xda|xiino", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Multiline);
    Regex v = new Regex(@"1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Multiline);
    if ((b.IsMatch(u) || v.IsMatch(u.Substring(0, 4)))) {
        isMobile = true;
    }
```

This solution is described [here](http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/)