# Asp.Net 5 MVC 6 detect mobile browser

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

How is it possible in **Asp.Net 5 MVC 6** to detect if the user is on a mobile device?

In previous version of `Asp MVC` it could be done like this:

```
Request.Browser.IsMobileDevice
```

The problem is that the namespace `System.Web` is not used by `Asp.Net 5`.

The `Request` variable in the controller actions is now of type `Microsoft.AspNet.Http.HttpRequest`, the old version was of type [`System.Web.HttpRequestBase`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequestbase%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

`Microsoft.AspNet.Http.HttpRequest` does not contain the `Browser` property. I tried looking through other properties, but didn't find anything.

**EDIT:** as requested some resources that prove that `Asp.Net 5` does not use `System.Web` anymore.
From the [Asp.Net documentation](http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/conceptual-overview/aspnet.html)

> ASP.NET 5 is no longer based on System.Web.dll, but is instead based
>   on a set of granular and well factored NuGet packages allowing you to
>   optimize your app to have just what you need.

Comment: why System.Web is now deprecated? Have you any documentation on it ?

Comment: @MahbuburRahman - it is not deprecated perse, it is a new platform built for mobile and cloud first. what you have in previous versions of ASP.NET do not necessarily exist any longer in ASP.NET 5 as the entire design is changed (or most of the design/engine).- have a quick (albeit slightly outdated) read:https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/magazine/dn879354.aspx

Comment: @MahbuburRahman as Ahmed said, it is not really deprecated, Asp.Net just isnt based on it anymore. I've changed the wording to remove the confusion.

Comment: This is not really an answer, but maybe you you should think about *why* you need to do this. If it's for the UI, you can get around this with responsive frameworks like Twitter Bootstrap. Detecting mobile isn't necessary there.

Comment: @ashes999 thanks for the advice. In this particular case I need it because the mobile application should receive different data than the desktop application.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The [implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1829089/how-does-ismobiledevice-work) of `Request.Browser.IsMobileDevice` relied on the **.browser files**, which AFAIK are not part of ASP.Net 5.

> Let's see if someone from the team can shed some light on how they plan to implement this. There is an entry in [the asp docs](http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/mobile/index.html) about mobile specific views, so they must have some plans for it.

In the meantime I guess you can create your own helper method parsing the query string, for example using the regex from [detectmobilebrowsers.com](http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/). For an alternative (and less extensive) regex see [detecting a mobile browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11381673/detecting-a-mobile-browser) in SO.

Following this idea, a temporal solution like this extension method might help while the asp team provides their solution:

```
public static class RequestExtensions
{
    //regex from http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/
    private static readonly Regex b = new Regex(@"(android|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|mobile.+firefox|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows ce|xda|xiino", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Multiline);
    private static readonly Regex v = new Regex(@"1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Multiline);

    public static bool IsMobileBrowser(this HttpRequest request)
    {
        var userAgent = request.UserAgent();            
        if ((b.IsMatch(userAgent) || v.IsMatch(userAgent.Substring(0, 4))))
        {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    public static string UserAgent(this HttpRequest request)
    {
        return request.Headers["User-Agent"];
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Daniel, do you know how to differentiate between mobile or tablet?