# Request.Browser.IsMobileDevice equivalent in ASP.Net Core (2.0)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

In legacy asp.net and asp.net MVC, we could easily check if the request is from mobile device by using `IsMobileDevice` property of the request (`System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Browser.IsMobileDevice`) but in **asp.net core** due to huge structural and architectural changes in `Request` class (`Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Request`), this property (`Browser.IsMobileDevice`)  doesn't exist anymore. Is there any **official** **equivalent from Microsoft** for .NetCore to addres this issue (I mean utility method or something)??.

Do note that I can easily write a method that does this by **checking user agent** property of `Request` class like below but It's not completely reliable because due to variety of user agents and updating and adding new user agents I can't grantee that my regex variables cover all the possible user agents and moreover I would have to update them (regex variables values) from time to time to keep them up-to-date.

Here is my code, but I don't wanna use it, it's not good practice though. I'm looking for a better alternative

```
static Regex MobileCheck = new Regex(@"(android|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|mobile.+firefox|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows ce|xda|xiino", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Multiline | RegexOptions.Compiled);
static Regex MobileVersionCheck = new Regex(@"1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Multiline | RegexOptions.Compiled);

public static bool BrowserIsMobile(Request request)
{
    var u = request.Headers["HTTP_USER_AGENT"].ToString();

    if (u.Length < 4)
        return false;

    if (MobileCheck.IsMatch(u) || MobileVersionCheck.IsMatch(u.Substring(0, 4)))
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

Comment: You should use such switches anymore and instead create responsive UIs (in pure html/css/javascript) which dynamically change the layout of your website based on the device size. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsive_web_design

Comment: As per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1829089/how-does-ismobiledevice-work IsMobile uses the same technique.

Comment: @Pawel your link is for .net not .netcore. I have no issue .net but this property doesn't exist any more in .net core

Comment: I am saying that .Net is also parsing user agent with regexes to return this information.

Comment: @Pawel yes, of course because there is no other way to do so.But it's not that simple as I read your link's first answer microsoft also check *.browser files which are inside .net directory

Comment: @Pawel even if it's just a simple regex check I'd rather not do it myself because if I use a build in .net core functionality instead first It's widely used and more reliable (than doing it myself) and second I don't need to worry about updating my regex values to support new user agents.

Comment: @Tseng you have to use the switches if your mobile site is Amp.

Comment: Best solution I've found: stackoverflow.com/a/71053664/7204020 Works like a charm in asp.net core.

Answer (score 5):

it can be achieved by creating a class that injects HttpContext and contain a method that read "User-Agent" and apply the same regular expression to detect is mobile browser or not

```
public class MyUtility
{
    HttpContext httpContext;
    public MyUtility(HttpContext _httpContext)
    {
        httpContext = _httpContext;
    }

    Regex MobileCheck = new Regex(@"(android|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|mobile.+firefox|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows ce|xda|xiino", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Multiline | RegexOptions.Compiled);
    Regex MobileVersionCheck = new Regex(@"1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Multiline | RegexOptions.Compiled);

    public bool IsMobileDeviceBrowser()
    {
        var u = httpContext.Request.Headers["User-Agent"].ToString();
        bool IsMobileBrowser = false;
        if (u.Length > 4 && (MobileCheck.IsMatch(u) || MobileVersionCheck.IsMatch(u.Substring(0, 4))))
            IsMobileBrowser = true;
        return IsMobileBrowser;
    }
}
```

then you can consume inside any controller or startup class as below

```
public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapGet("/", async httpContext =>
            {
               if(new MyUtility(httpContext).IsMobileDeviceBrowser())
                await httpContext.Response.WriteAsync("Is Mobile Browser ");
                else
                await httpContext.Response.WriteAsync("Is Desktop Browser ");
            });
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Code_Worm is this answer your question I tried on sample core application and work fine with me